# How to make iframe pop-up in dialog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, actionview

"Complete an Offer") %>

When a user clicks the button, I want an iframe* to pop-up in a separate dialog box.  Any pointers?

*

Answer (score 1):

Aside from a simple js alert box, Rails doesn't have anything for this out of the box.  You could roll your own making a custom helper to do what you want or try using a plugin like facebox_link_to.

http://handlino.com/blog/2008/02/26/57/